# Select many row at once in the table

Tags: jquery

Today you can make a sinlge selection but If I want to select everything by checkboxing the input box (left of the text "Name").

I don't know how to do it?

Info.
Another thing to take account to. If you have selected a single row and them you want to select everyting included the selected one or many.
And also one thing. The header should not be selected by changing the background color.

Thanks!

```js
$("table input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
    }  
});
```

```css
tr.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Location 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
            <td>Location 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 3</td>
            <td>Location 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

"http://jsfiddle.net/jcftsazk/9/"

Comment: Did any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use classes for this. Then just when the header checkbox is clicked, just loop trough all other checkboxs and checked or de-checked them. This is an example.

```js
$('#headerCheckBox').click(function () {
    var checked = $("#headerCheckBox").is(':checked');
   $(".checkbox").each(function () {
     $(this).prop('checked', checked);
     if (checked) {
          $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
       } 
       else {
          $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
       } 
   });
});
```

```css
.rows.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input id="headerCheckBox" type="checkbox"/></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rows">
            <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>Location 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rows">
            <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 2</td>
            <td>Location 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rows">
            <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>Name 3</td>
            <td>Location 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine by selecting single row?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes of course just add the other method you had.

Comment: I gonna need some help from you. I have applied the code "https://jsfiddle.net/5rf4s885/5/" and when I use it in a big project the row of header also will be selected. Is it possible to add a new source that says if the id named #headerCheckBox is in the input checkbox it shall not be selected or affected. It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: Is it possible to not make the first tr (with header) not to contain any "class="selected""?

Comment: @HelloWorld the jsfidd is 404

Comment: IC.. In the end I was enable to solve it. Thanks you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing checking the boxes on select all try this...

https://jsfiddle.net/sdc90qev/1/

```
$('#selectall').change(function() {
  var checkboxes = $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox');
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      checkboxes.prop('checked', 'checked');
      $('tr').addClass('selected');
  } else {
        checkboxes.prop('checked', '');
        $('tr').removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

add id="selectall" to the th

```
 <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox" /></th>
```

Comment: If you select everyting, is it possible to not make a background selection for the heading row?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to header row that will select all of the `tr` elements and highlights them.

```
$("#header").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var t = $("tr").slice(1);
        t.addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('tr').removeClass('selected');
    }  
});
```

Then use the CSS3 `:not()` selector for the other check box clicks

```
$("table input[type=checkbox]:not(#header)").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
       $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
    }  
});
```

here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcftsazk/11/

Update:

I have updated the fiddle to check all of the check boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/jcftsazk/12/

```
$("#header").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var t = $("tr").slice(1);
        t.addClass('selected');
        $("input[type=checkbox]", t).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $("input[type=checkbox]", t).prop("checked", false);
    }  
});
```

I use `$("input[type=checkbox]", t)` to select only the check boxes with in the set of the tables check boxes.

Comment: If you make a selection of everything I also would like to check to all input box, if possible.